# Find $(1+i)^i$ in simpler terms, without imaginary exponents.

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function, irrational-numbers

I was asked to find $(1+i)^i$, I don't know what to do when there is an imaginary component in the exponent.

since $1+i=\sqrt{2}e^{-\frac{1}{4}i \pi}$ then $(1+i)^i = \sqrt{2}^i e^{\frac{1}{4} \pi}$ but now we run into the same problem again, what is $\sqrt{2}^i$?

Comment: btw the answer is $e^{-\frac{1}{4}\pi-2\pi k}((\cos (\frac{1}{2} \ln 2)+i\sin(\frac{1}{2}\ln 2))$

Comment: You have a sign wrong in the exponent: $1 + i = \sqrt 2 e^{+\frac14i\pi}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $x$ is any positive number then $x^i = e^{i\ln x} = \cos(\ln x) + i\sin(\ln x)$.

Comment: what about $x^{2i}$? do exponential rules work? can i say its $(x^2)^i$?

Comment: IT's kind a weird result. Because that means that $x^i$ is always on the unit circle. $|2^i| = |4^i|$ is counter intuitive.

Comment: Here's another way to think about it. $e^{i\theta}$ is on the unit circle and can also be written as $(e^\theta)^i$; $e^\theta$ can be made equal to any positive number.